# Existence of non continuous Linear transformation

Tags: normed-spaces

Given that $M, N$ are normed linear space over same scaler, $\dim M=\infty, N\ne\{0\}$, we need to show existence of a linear transformation $T : M\to N$ which is not continuous.

I am not having a clue to start but I know one example $f\mapsto f'$ on $C^1[0,1]$,Thank you very much for your reply

Comment: If $M$ is separable, you can always kind of mimic the derivative. Pick a countable basis $e_1,...,e_n,...$ and let $Te_n=ne_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every vector space $M$ has a so called Hamel basis. Namely, a set $ H = \{ v_{\lambda} \in M : \lambda \in \Lambda \}$ such that every $v \in M$ has a unique expression as finite linear combination of elements of $M$: $$v = \sum_{j=1}^{n(v)} x_j \,  v_{\lambda_j} \, .$$ 
If $M$ has infinite dimension then the index set $\Lambda$ has infinite elements so there exists an unbounded real function $\rho : \Lambda \to \mathbb{R}$. Since $N \neq \{ 0 \}$ there is a unit vector $u \in N$. Now define $T$ in the Hamel basis to be $$ T(v_{\lambda}) = \rho(\lambda) \| v_{\lambda}\| u $$
and extend $T$ by linearity to get $T : M \to N$. Claim $T$ is not continuous. Indeed, since $\rho$ is unbounded there is a sequence of unit vectors $w_i := \frac{v_{\lambda_i}}{\| v_{\lambda_i}\|}$ such that $T(w_i) = \rho(\lambda_i) u$ is unbounded.